# Firebase Functions: 'onCreate' function isn't being called

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, algolia

I'm developing a diary app for Android that uses Firebase's Realtime database to store `memory` objects. A `memory` object consists of `title, image, text, list of tags, and more...`

When the user posts a new memory to the database, I want to make the memory searchable by indexing it to Algolia. For that I deploy this function to my Firebase Functions project:

```
exports.indexentry = functions.database.ref('/Diary/{userId}/{memoryId}').onCreate(
async (data, context) => {
  const index = client.initIndex(ALGOLIA_MEMORIES_INDEX_NAME);
  const firebaseObject = {
    text: data.val(),
    objectID: context.params.memoryId
  };

  await index.saveObject(firebaseObject);
  return data.after.ref.parent.child('last_index_timestamp').set(Date.parse(context.timestamp));
});
```

But this function is not being called when new memory is uploaded. Can someone help me to recognise the problem?

EDIT: After checking in the Cloud Function log I discovered that the function is called, but a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'ref' of undefined` error occurred.

Comment: Hello, you need to give us more info... What do you mean by "this function is not being called"? Do you see something in the Cloud Function log? What if you put a `console.log()` in your code-. Are you sure you don't write to Cloud Firestore instead of the Realtime database?

Comment: Can you show what you do that should trigger this function? So either the code that writes a memory, or the actions you take in the Firebase console.

Comment: Thank you, @RenaudTarnec! Your intent helped me to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the `TypeError: Cannot read property 'ref' of undefined` error by changing the function code from:

```
return data.after.ref.parent.child('last_index_timestamp').set(Date.parse(context.timestamp));
```

to:

```
return data.ref.parent.child('last_index_timestamp').set(Date.parse(context.timestamp));
```

I think the reason for this error is because of the `data` Change object of `onCreate()` function haven't an `after` variable.